# VBA to format PNEZD string in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large list of points with PNEZD (point, northing, easting, elevation, description) fallowed by a few attributes for each point. how can I combine these extra attribute columns to my D column separated by a space? And can i do that with a push of a button?

example of a few points would be

```
10,1000,5000,50,tree,birch,12IN

11,1100,5500,55,tree,spruce,10IN

12,1130,5560,54,powerpole,tele,wood,12IN,guyed
```

I want to combine the last few so it will read:

```
10,1000,5000,50,tree birch 12IN

11,1100,5500,55,tree spruce 10IN

12,1130,5560,54,powerpole tele wood 12IN guyed
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user-defined function in VBA that you can then use on your worksheet as any normal formula.

From Excel, press Alt+F11 to get to the VBA editor. Once there, press Ctrl+R to show or activate the Project Explorer. Right-click on the Modules node, and select Insert -> Module. Put the code below into the module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetPnezdLabel(pnezd As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Dim result As Variant
    Dim parts As Variant
    Dim lastPartIndex As Long
    Dim intermediatePartIndex As Long
    Dim index As Long

    result = ""

    parts = Split(CStr(pnezd), ",", Compare:=VbCompareMethod.vbBinaryCompare)
    lastPartIndex = UBound(parts)
    intermediatePartIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(3, lastPartIndex)

    For index = 0 To intermediatePartIndex
        result = result & parts(index) & IIf(index < lastPartIndex, ",", "")
    Next

    For index = 4 To lastPartIndex
        result = result & parts(index) & IIf(index < lastPartIndex, " ", "")
    Next

Done:
    GetPnezdLabel = result
    Exit Function

errHandler:
    result = XlCVError.xlErrValue
    Resume Done
End Function
```

Press Alt+F11 to return to Excel. Now, assuming you have a PNEZD value in cell `A1`, you can create a formula in e.g. `B1` as follows:

```
=GetPnezdLabel(A1)
```

and you'll see the result appear.

The principle behind the GetPnezdLabel function is to split the parameter's value at commas and to build the result from the parts.

Answer (score 0):

For information, the same result can be achieved through following formula.

Assuming your data is in cell **A2** then in cell **D2** insert following formula and copy down.

`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",199),4),199))
&","&
SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",199),4),199)),","," ")`

As you've indicated VBA specifically, you may not want a formula solution.